# htaccess exclude folder from rule

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I have the following working rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

However this prevents my admin panel to work. Is it possible to exclude a directory and its subfolders from this rule?

**Exclude folders like this (exclude `panel` folder):**

```
/panel/
/panel/a-subfolder/
/panel/a-subfolder/deeper/
```

They should work without the rule, without the ending slash as well like `/panel/a-subfolder`

**Don't exclude folders like this:**

```
/another-unknown-folder/
/some-other-folder/folder/folder2/
```

They should follow the rule, force slash as the rule does today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional `RewriteCond` for exclusion:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/panel/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```